# How can I push .Net Framework API to PCF?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, push, cloud-foundry

I am trying to push my .Net Native API to Pivotal Cloud Foundry. Below is the command I am giving for pushing my API.

```
 cf push API-Name -s windows2012R2 -b binary_buildpack -c "start" -m 1G -p C:/Path
```

While running it will say "No start command detected" but when I did -c ? it showed me that start was a command. Then when I look at the log file it will show me:

ERR Could not determine a start command. Use the -c flag to 'cf push' to specify a custom start command.

and at the end it will say:

ERR Failed to create container

"reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_description"=>"failed to initialize container"

Am I running the command wrong or is there something I need to do to my API to make it compatible?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I had to set the health check off and my app and all instances are started now.

```
    cf set-health-check NAME none
```

Comment: If you have an application receiving web requests, I would advise against this. This setting is how the platform watches your app and makes sure that it's still ready to receive requests.  If you set this to none, all the platform will monitor is your process and as long as that's running your app will be "healthy".  This means your app can get into a situation where it's not taking requests but still "healthy" because the process is still running.  The platform won't be able to detect this class of problem though and it won't be able to automatically restart your application.

Comment: That makes sense. Do you know of anything else that might be better than setting the health check to none?

Comment: I'm not a Windows guy, so I can't help you much.  You might want to look at the HWC Build pack.  I think that's replacing the usage of the binary build pack for Windows apps on PCF for many cases.  Outside of that, bump up the log level in your app as much as possible and capture `cf logs` to see what is happening in your app.  Is it starting?  What port is it listening to?  Is it taking any requests before it crashes?  How long does it run before it crashes?  All could help to narrow down what's happening before it crashes & ultimately why it's crashing.